# Can I create an X509 certificate without an external module in the node.js environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make X509 certificate only with internal module.
Please let me know if you have any code, link, or data available.

I tried the new X509Certificate() in the crypto module, but only an error was printed.

The node version uses 16.14.2 and uses cjs.

Comment: Of course it is possible, you don't even need the `crypto` module. You just have to implement all the cryptographic algorithms and specifications yourself ... But no, it is not possbile to create a new certificate with the `X509Certificate` class from the crytpo module. This is only for reading an existing certificate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Node's crypto Library to Create a Self-signed Certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624143/using-nodes-crypto-library-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate)